# Xib file: Can't drag a View from a xib file to a swift file

Tags: xcode, swift, ios9

I just dragged and dropped a View to a xib file. I added some constrains and tried to Ctrl drag from the View to a .swift file with the assistant editor, but it bounce back, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xib file needs to be a subclass of the file you are trying to ctrl+drag to.

[image]

Comment: the xib file is a subclass of the file i created. and i didn't have to do go to Class and select UIView I just clean and restarted my program and it got fixed. thanks for the help tough.

Answer (score 3):

I was setting the View's custom class instead of the File's Owner. Once I set the File's Owner to the custom class, I was able to control-drag from the view in the storyboard over to my class. Hope this helps someone.