# Changing a .swift to connect to a Table View Controller not a View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have an IOS app that displays items. I have a working "MYItemCell.xib" and a "MYItemCell.swift". I have just added a new type of item that will be displayed somewhat differently. It is named: MYItemTwoCell.xib/swift

Right now I am trying to keep most of it the same, so I just copied over both the .xib and the swift file and renamed things. But I cannot connect my new .xib to my new .swift. It remains connected to the old .swift

I was having this problem: [Xib file: Can't drag a View from a xib file to a swift file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671642/xib-file-cant-drag-a-view-from-a-xib-file-to-a-swift-file) . So I tried to make the "container" in the .xib file of the class in my .swift file.

But, when I write in my new class name "MYItemTwoCell" it always reverts back the "MYItemCell"

When I click the down arrow on the selector it only suggests "UITableViewCell" and "MYItemTwoCell" is not listed.

**EDIT 1**

I believe the issue that the MYItemCellTwo cannot be a UICollectionViewCell. It will connect to a blank UIViewController that I add. In other words: I cannot make a UICollectionViewCell a MYItemTwoCell class but I can make a UIViewController a MYItemTwoCell class.

Does anyone know how to make my MYItemTwoCell a UICollectionViewCell class not a UIViewController class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Identifier inspector from the MYItemTwoCell.xib file and reference your MYItemTwoCell.swift file.

[image]

Don't worry if you not see it, write class name.

Comment: Note this in my question: 'But, when I write in my new class name "MYItemTwoCell" it always reverts back the "MYItemCell"'. After writing it in and clicking enter, the mac makes a "boop" sound and it does not work. If I leave the page and come back to it. The class is still "MYItemCell"

Comment: If I change it to UITableViewCell. I also cannot change it back to MYItemCell even though it was that to begin with

Comment: Have you used a different identifier in Attribute inspector?

Comment: If I add an identifier the class text box still behaves the same way